# Transfer SQL to MySQL C# Monitoring Program

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I currently have a working program that is monitoring a few SQL tables and transferring data to MySQL tables.  Essentially, I have a loop that checks every 30 seconds.  My main concern is that I currently need to close and open the connection every time I loop.  The reason for this is because I was getting errors about multiple transactions.  When I close my connections, I also need to dispose the connection.  I thought that disposing the transactions would have solved this problem, but I was still getting errors about multiple transactions.

This all seems to be working fine but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this without closing the connection.

Comment: Do you have any code you can show us?

Comment: Some code would be great, particularly how you are creating your db connection. Also, the transaction errors would be good too.

Comment: It's better to open the connection directly before using and close directly after doing whatever you need with the DB. If you're just doing a type of sync program there should be no reason to keep the connection open.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your errors but it seems that you have to increase the number of connections to the remote computer. Have a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.configuration.connectionmanagementelement.maxconnection.aspx

Also you can try to do is use only one connection to realize multiple SQLs.

If it is doesn't help then please provide your code to check it...

Answer (score 0):

Were you committing your transactions in your loop? `transaction.Commit()` ... that could have been the issue... Hard to say with no code. No need to worry about opening and closing connections anyways since ADO.NET uses connection pooling behind the scenes. You only actually 'open' a connection the first time, after that is kept open in the pool to be used again. As others have said though, Post some code!